# Entity Framework 7 AddRange() Not Adding Foreign Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've been using EF Code First for awhile but this is my first time with EF7.

I have the following Model classes where Venue has a one-to-many relationship to Show:

```
public class Show
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Venue Venue { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class Venue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    //...
    public List<Show> Shows { get; set; }
}
```

I set up the DBContext like this:

```
public class NettlesContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Show> Shows { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Venue> Venues { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        new ShowConfiguration(builder.Entity<Show>());
        new ImageConfiguration(builder.Entity<Image>());
    }
}

public class ShowConfiguration
{
    public ShowConfiguration(EntityTypeBuilder<Show> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.Id).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(p => p.Title).IsRequired();
    } 
}

public class VenueConfiguration
{
    public VenueConfiguration(EntityTypeBuilder<Venue> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.Id).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Then in some start up code I initialize the database like this:

```
    private static void AddShows(NettlesContext db)
    {
        var shows = new List<Show>()
        {
            new Show()
            {
                Title = "Portland Country Dance Community Contra Dance",
                Venue = new Venue()
                {
                    Name = "Fulton Community Center",
                },
            },
            new Show()
            {
                Title = "Portland Roadhouse Contra Dance",
                Venue = new Venue()
                {
                    Name = "Milwaukie Community Club",
                },
            },
        };

        db.Shows.AddRange(shows);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The Shows table is properly initialized except that the VenueId is null.  The Venue table is entirely empty.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a second argument to `DbSet.Add`.

```
Add(TEntity entity, GraphBehavior behavior = GraphBehavior.IncludeDependents)
```

Although the default is to `IncludeDependents` (aka children entities), EF7's behavior of `Add()` is not identifying `Venue` as a child of `Show`. In your `OnModelCreating` you need to specify the relationship between `Venue` and `Show`. See [Relationships](http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html) in the EF7 Docs.

Example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Venue>(entityBuilder =>
{
    entityBuilder
        .HasMany(v => v.Shows)
        .WithOne(s => s.Venue)
        .HasForeignKey(s => s.VenueId);
});
```

Even with this however, you will still need to call .Add on the new instances of Venue because Show is not a dependent (child) of Venue.

```
private static void AddShows(NettlesContext db)
{
    var fulton = new Venue()
            {
                Name = "Fulton Community Center",
            };
    var club = new Venue()
            {
                Name = "Milwaukie Community Club",
            };
    db.Venues.Add(fulton);
    db.Venues.Add(club);

    var shows = new List<Show>()
    {
        new Show()
        {
            Title = "Portland Country Dance Community Contra Dance",
            Venue = fulton,
        },
        new Show()
        {
            Title = "Portland Roadhouse Contra Dance",
            Venue = club
        },
    };
    context.Shows.AddRange(shows);
}
```

*Worth noting: this behavior of .Add() has been a source of confusion in EF7 RC1 and its behavior may be changing in EF7 RC2. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/pull/4132*

Comment: "builder.HasMany(v => v.Shows).HasOne(s => s.Venue).HasForeignKey(s => s.VenueId);" gives an undefined error for HasOne and  "builder.HasMany(v => v.Shows).WithOne(s => s.Venue).HasForeignKey(s => s.VenueId);"  gives the following error during migration: "The properties expression 's => Convert(s.VenueId)' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.
Parameter name: propertyAccessExpression"

Comment: builder.HasMany(v => v.Shows).WithOne(s => s.Venue) compiles and migrates but even with 
 db.Shows.AddRange(shows, GraphBehavior.IncludeDependents);
Same problem as before.

Comment: yup. WithOne vs HasOne. (update above). As I mentioned though, you still need to call .Add() on the instances of Venue as Venue is not considered a dependent of Venue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your model as this

```
public class Venue
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name {get; set; }
  //...
  public List<Show> Shows { get; set; }
 }
public class Show
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int VenueId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("VenueId")]
  public Venue Venue { get; set; }
  //...
}
```

ForegnKey attribute is used to define the foriegn key of the relation between two tables

Comment: Adding
[ForeignKey("VenueId")]
public int VenueId;
has no effect.